# In my Wordpress plugin, how do I save and retrieve Multiple indexed sets of data with the Settings API?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need my plugin to save and edit multiple *indexed* **sets** of key/value pairs on my custom settings page and retrieve later them by their index on the Appearance>>Widgets page.

Is it best to create a custom table in the database for this or does the Settings API have two dimensional accommodation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the short answer was to go ahead and expand the existing wordpress database. That is because the Settings API really only goes one dimensional and would be a very inefficient use of the database. https://pippinsplugins.com/custom-database-api-reasons-for-custom-tables-and-an-api/

EDIT: Pippin no longer offers this without a paid membership, but an older version is still available via the internet archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20160611220718/https://pippinsplugins.com/custom-database-api-reasons-for-custom-tables-and-an-api/   If Pippin helps you, I encourage you to try his membership.  It has tons of useful wordpress goodies.